# can i create multiple image animation without setting layers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

Can anyone tell me that how can i get multiple images stored in an array so that the image will animate depending on that array provided.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `UIImageView` and the `animationImages` property, you can set an array of images. You can then set the `animationDuration` and `animationRepeatCount` property to control the animation.

Comment: thanks for your faster reply but i already do it properly. see i want to create playing cards game like [poker] so i want to draw cards with animation to each player. the card to the player is unique id so tell me how can iuse it. see the link of blog of my code.                                                                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763199/i-wan-to-place-imageview-at-different-position-with-animation

Comment: Ok, so this question has been answered then? Please update your question, I don't understand what you need.

Comment: please refer my code at given link all descreption and my code is there so its my humble request to you please refer it and if i made any mistake please tell me....

Comment: Problem is, I don't get the connection between your question here and the code there.

Comment: Link -:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763199/i-wan-to-place-imageview-at-different-position-with-animation                                                           i want to create game just like Poker cards gmae so can you help me for it.